# Copy QTreeWidgetItem from QPushButton item widget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidgetitem

I'd like to copy a QTreeWidgetItem, if a push-button is pushed within it.

So far I've got:

```
def Copy(self):
    obj = self.sender()

self.Tree = qt.QTreeWidget(self)
self.Tree.setHeaderLabels(["Name"])  

item = qt.QTreeWidgetItem("Name") 
self.Tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

childItem = qt.QTreeWidgetItem("Name") #<------- This I'd like to copy

item.addChild(childItem)

bttn = qt.QPushButton("Copy This Widget", self)
bttn.clicked.connect(self.Copy)

self.Tree.setItemWidget(childItem, 1, bttn)
```

I'd like to be able to copy `childItem`, so that I may place it in a QTreeWidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to get the `QTreeWidgetItem` from its item-widget, so you will have to explicitly store the index somewhere so that it can be accessed later.

One way to do this is to add the index to the item-widget as a property:

```
bttn = qt.QPushButton("Copy This Widget", self)
index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.Tree.indexFromItem(childItem))
bttn.setProperty('index', index)    

...

def Copy(self):
    index = self.sender().property('index')
    if index.isValid():
        copyItem = qt.QTreeWidgetItem(self.Tree.itemFromIndex(index))
```

Comment: Well I'm trying to copy the QTreeWidgetItem which the button was pressed from.

Comment: @vandelay. Your question is quite unclear, but see my updated answer.